# One course/subject, one class, two lecturers

Tags: teaching

This is my first question here, so please correct me if I'm wrong in my way of asking.

My question is suggested directly by the title. In my college institution, for each subject, half of the semester is handled by one lecture, and the next half by another one. The reasoning is that each lecturer needs to have near equal teaching responsibility. If one lecturer only is applied, there might be some lecturers who have lower or higher workloads than others.

Another reasoning is that this way we can minimize the bias that can happen with just one lecturer. If a lecturer has bias over some students but the other does not, it will somehow even out, rather than just this first lecturer handles the whole semester.

Some negative effects are there of course, such as content bias and assessment related problem, but how do you think the negative or positive effects are affecting the learning and teaching experience? My heart says the negatives are just too much.

Eventhough this has been the tradition, my math program, if possible, would like to evaluate this and possibly make changes.

Comment: Double post: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/111892/two-lecturers-one-course-one-class . Please do not post to two SE websites at once; wait for one site to deal with the question and, if those are not satisfactory, post to the other with link to the previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1)  Definitely sounds like a system optimized for the teacher, not the student.

(2)  Somehow the rest of the free world manages to deal with the opposite arrangement and teaching workload varies from semester to semester for individual teachers.

(Therefore, 3) I suggest you are right.

(4) To strengthen the argument and help you versus the opposition...come up with (a) examples (e.g. student critiques) to show the damage to student and (b) come up with examples of other schools which just manage with teachers having variability...maybe sample 10 randomly and see how many do what you do (I bet 1 or less).

Comment: (1) I kinda agree with you. However in my case, it looks like looking at other institutions has automatically been done and yet nothing has changed tho hmm

Comment: Maybe this method was deduced just by our own institution. That's the issue with point (4) for the decision maker I think, tho I pretty much agree with (4).

Comment: Maybe decide if you care enough to fight it.  Realistically, given your (Bayesian guessed) position, you are better off not fighting city hall and just dealing with the situation as it is and concentrating on other things.